# SendGrid API Status

Tags: sendgrid

Is there a way to programmatically get the status of the SendGrid API?  For example:

https://status.sendgrid.com/

This page gives that information.  I see there is a call to https://status.sendgrid.com/api/v2/status.json on this page, but that seems to give just a general status.  I'm more interested in the individual items in this list.

Comment: Anyone else looking for more info on this, have a quick nosy at - https://status.sendgrid.com/api

Answer (score 0):

There's no official API but you can make use of the "Subscribe To Updates" feature and follow the RSS feed, Twitter account, or add a webhook to receive updates.

[image]